# Micronaut ConfigurationProperties not resolving environment variables

Tags: java, environment-variables, micronaut, micronaut-data, micronaut-client

I have a micronaut app with application.yaml having this configuration:

```yaml
confluent:
    name: Consumer Events Registry
    base_url: abcd-xyz.westus2.azure.confluent.cloud
    secrets:
      access_key: ${CONFLUENT_KEY}
      secret: ${CONFLUENT_SECRET}
```

I have set CONFLUENT_SECRET and CONFLUENT_SECRET as env variables (through .bashrc) and I'm using the following ConfigurationProperties class to parse it:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties("confluent")
public class ConfluentRegistryConfig {
    private String name;
    private String baseUrl;
    private SecretsConfig secrets;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class SecretsConfig {
        @JsonProperty("access_key") private String accessKey;
        @JsonProperty("secret") private String secret;
    }
}
```

It reads the `name` and `baseUrl` properly but for access_key and secret it reads the "${CONFLUENT_KEY}" and "${CONFLUENT_SECRET}" strings as value. I was hoping that ConfigurationProperties could resolve these env variables but it does not appear to do so.

I also tried using them like `{env. CONFLUENT_KEY}`, `{{env.CONFLUENT_KEY}}` and `${env. CONFLUENT_KEY}` but it reads them as string and does not resolve them.